# Implement half away from 0 rounding

Tags: code-challenge, arithmetic

### Overview:

Using you language of choice, implement a complete "[half away from 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking)" rounding function in the shortest amount of code possible.

### Rules/Constraints:

- Direct, predefined `Round`-like functions are not allowed.
- `Floor`/`Ceiling`-type functions *are* allowed, if your language supports these.
- Function shall be able to handle 32-bit floating-point values.
- Function shall be able to correctly handle negative values (see examples).
- This is Golf, so shortest code wins.
- Correct rounding for this challenge is to round away from 0, such that a rounded value will have an equal or larger absolute value.

### Input/Output:

- Your function shall take two parameters:

  - The first is a float `x`, which is the value to round.
  - The second is an integer `n`, which is the number of decimal places to round to.
  - `x` can be a whole number or contain a decimal part, fitting within a 32-bit, single-precision float.
  - `n` can be greater than or equal to 0, and may be larger than the number of decimal places in `x`.
- Output will be the correctly rounded `x`.
- **In cases where the solution is not exactly representable in IEEE float format, the output should be the logical representation you would have figured if not using a computer. i.e. The output of `Round(0.125, 2)` should be `0.13`*.

### Example I/O:

```
Round(1.23456789, 7)
1.2345679

Round(1.234, 5)
1.234 OR 1.23400 (Your choice on trailing 0)

Round(-0.5, 0)
-1 NOT 0

Round(-0.123, 2)
-0.12 NOT -0.13

Round(3.1415926535897932384626433832, 20)
3.14159265358979323846
```

### Winning:

***Some system limitations may be present which make your function less accurate/usable.* In these cases, supply the best possible calculation you can within those limitations.

For example, I have a solution in my preferred environment, VBA in Office 2003, which only allows me to round up to 307 digits, while the IDE will only let me use values up to 15 significant decimal places. (I will eventually post this example here.)

With your answer submission, please post the highest values of `n` and the largest number of significant decimal digits for `x` for which your function will run. If you cannot meet the minimum requirements, that solution is disqualified, no matter the code length. (i.e. my own solution described above is invalid)

While this is code golf, and the shortest code will generally win. If two answers exist with different maximum values for `x` and `n`, the solution which works with the highest input values (measured as `x * n`) will win. If these two solutions meet the same limitation while fulfilling the requirements of the challenge, then the shortest code of those two will win.

If no solutions meet the requirement, then the best limitation score (shortest code length in the event of a tie) will win.

Example submission given the rules above for my own code:

```
<CODE HERE>
Max n = 307
Max x digits = 15
Limitation Score (x * n) = 4605
```

Comment: Ehm, you say that 15 decimal places is a limitation, and you give examples like 1.23456789, but you also say that it should handle single precision floats. So which one is it?

Comment: @MrLister The spec is to be able to handle Singles. For what I am able to come up with on my own, as an example only, I am personally limited to 15 characters. In other words, my own solution is not valid for this challenge. `1.23456789` is again for example only.

Comment: What is your rounding rule for exact halves? Based on the example of -0.5 it could be away from 0 or nearest odd number; you should make it explicit because a) it's ambiguous; b) those are both weird rules. (The standard rules are half-up, half-down, or half-even).

Comment: What constitutes "correctly rounded"?

Comment: @Gaffi see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking

Comment: Thanks for the link, @ardnew. I am still going to go with away from 0. Updating question...

Comment: What should we return when the rounded value isn't exactly representable?  For instance `Round(.125,2)`.  `.125` is exactly representable, but `.13` isn't.

Comment: @KeithRandall I don't know that I understand... Why is `.13` not a good response for that input?

Comment: @Gaffi: because it isn't exactly representable in IEEE float format.  The closest IEEE (64 bit) number to `.13` is approximately `0.13000000000000000444`.

Comment: @KeithRandall Thanks for explaining. In that case, the output should be the logical representation you would have figured if not using a computer. i.e. the output should be `.13`. I'll add to the quesiton.

Comment: That doesn't make sense as an answer to @Keith's question, assuming that the return type of Round is float. Or is it meant to return a string?

Comment: @PeterTaylor To that point, I suppose I did not specify the format of the output. My intent was to be able to read the value as would be calculated by hand (in someone's head) without the caveats that a float presents. I will say that the output can be in any data format, so long as the numeric format works within those bounds already explained (and which you correctly edited). If it is not possible - using the data type you return -  to print the value in the correct format, then another output data type will be necessary (i.e. a string, as you've pointed out).

Comment: @Gaffi The example you posted says `Round(0.123, 2)` should be `0.13`, but I believe you meant to say `Round(0.125, 2)`. I tried editing it for you, but it was rejected for some reason.

Comment: Floating point is tough to get right.  For instance, the IEEE 64-bit representation of `0.15` is a value close to `0.14999999999999999444`, so should `Round(0.15,1)` be `.1`, or `.2`?  Hmmm....

Comment: @ardnew Yes, Peter Taylor corrected that for me already.

Comment: @KeithRandall `Round(0.15,1)` should output `.2`. The determination should be based on the input, not necessarily how the system interprets it.

Comment: But you can't *pass in* `0.15` to `Round`.  It isn't a representable floating-point number.  In other words, when you write `Round(0.15,1)` in your source, what actually gets called at runtime is `Round(0.14999999999999999444,1)`.  You can't actually pass `0.15` to `Round` - the string `0.15` gets converted to a `float` (a.k.a. rounded to the nearest IEEE number) before the call happens.

Comment: In other words, your spec requires `Round(0.15,1)` and `Round(0.14999999999999999444,1)` to return different answers.  But to the code that implements `Round`, those are indistinguishable calls.

Comment: @KeithRandall I understand you. I may be outside of my league on this challenge, as I can't think of a great way to handle that. I should have taken this to the sandbox, but I thought (incorrectly) that this would be simple...  

This may be a bit convoluted, and perhaps incorrect as well, but would it be viable to round the float version of `x` to `n+1`, then round that? Or would that lead to the same issue already here?

Comment: @Gaffi: I don't think that helps.  Allowing some wiggle  room might, for instance you can round either way if [x-epsilon,x+epsilon] contains the halfway point.  But then the "half away from 0" part doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Gaffi maybe I'm being dense, but it doesn't appear to be corrected. you're referring to the last bullet under the `Input/Output:` section?

Comment: @ardnew That line was fixed, but not for the error you pointed out. I was being dense; you were correct. I've updated the post.

Comment: @KeithRandall This detracts a bit from the original challenge, but how about accepting a string input instead?

Comment: @Gaffi: don't worry, I'm happy with the challenge as-is.  Just have to be a bit lenient with holding people to the spec.

Comment: @ardnew, the text you added to pad your edit out to be long enough was factually incorrect (0.125 is 1/8 and so can be exactly represented in binary floating point), so I rejected it and made the two-character edit which the edit comment said was the edit you really wanted to make. Edit: doh, I missed that you also changed 0.123 to 0.125. Sorry.

Comment: @PeterTaylor oops, my mistake! thank you very much for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Q (29 Characters)

```
{("i"$x*10 xexp y)%10 xexp y}
```

Sample usage

```
{("i"$x*10 xexp y)%10 xexp y}[1.23456;4]
```

Works by multiplying your x input by 10 to the power of your y input, casting to an int and then dividing again by 10 to the power of your y input.

Comment: Deduplicate for great savings `{(6h$x*i)%i:10 xexp y}`.

Answer (score 1):

Python (153 chars, max(x)=infinite, max(n)=13)

You can input a float, however it works much, much better (max(n)=infinite instead of 13) if you input a string.

```
def Round(x,n):
    x=map(str,str(x))
    if n==0:x.remove('.')
    n+=1+(n!=0)+(x[0]=='-')
    if n<len(x):x[n-1]=str(int(x[n-1])+(x[n]>='5'))
    return''.join(x[:n])
```

Explanation:

`x=map(str,str(x))`
Seperate each character of `x`. (e.x. when x=5.4, running this makes x equal to `['5', '.', '4']`.

`if n==0:x.remove('.')`
A hack to get around Test Case 3, `Round(-0.5, 0)`. Removes the decimal so we don't get the output `-1.`

`n+=1+(n!=0)+(x[0]=='-')`
`if n<len(x):x[n-1]=str(int(x[n-1])+(x[n]>='5'))`

`1` compensates for the decimal point. I think.
`(n!=0)`: Compensates for the removal of the decimal point and allows the next line to run.
`(x[0]=='-')`: Makes it so that in the next line, the negative sign (an additional character) will not mess up the calculation.

`if n<len(x)`: Accounts for Test Case 2, `Round(1.234, 5)`, because Python errors when you try to access the `n`th item of a list if it's not there. (`x[5]` is called in the test case, and `x` does not have a 6th term.)
`x[n-1]=str(int(x[n-1])+(x[n]>='5'))`: Gets the `n-1`th item of `x` (which is a string, so it needs to be turned into a number), and adds 1 to it if the `n`th item of `x` is greater than or equal to 5. Then it gets turned back into a string.

`return''.join(x[:n])`: Returns the concatenation of everything up to the `n`th item in `x`.

Comment: `if n==0:x.remove('.') / A hack to get around Test Case 3, Round(-0.5, 0). Removes the decimal so we don't get the output -1.` But we do want `-1` as the output for that test case.

Comment: In line 4, try replacing `n[0]=='-'` with `x[0]=='-'`

Comment: @Gaffi: That's `-1.`, not `-1`

Comment: @Matt: Oops. I originally had my function as `Round(a, b)`, but translated it for clarity.

Comment: @beary605 Ah, I see. The period is *inside* the formatted string. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <strike>55</strike> 46 chars

```
R=lambda x,n:int(10**n*x+(.5,-.5)[x<0])/10.**n
```

Translates the decimal point, rounds half up using `int(x+.5)`, then translates the decimal point back.  Negative numbers use `int(x-.5)`.

Should be as accurate as a 64-bit IEEE can get (15+ decimal digits).  `n` can be up to about 300 or so (less if `x` is big).

Comment: It doesn't work when n=0. `R(3.123,0)` gives 3.0 instead of 3

Comment: I think this should fix the problem (56 chars): `R=lambda x,n:int(10**n*x+(.5,-.5)[x<0])/(10.,10)[n<1]**n`

Comment: @lortabac: I don't understand.  `3.0` and `3` are the same number.

Comment: @lortabac: Thanks for the negative number idea.

Comment: Ok, I think you are right. There are no formatting requirements in the rules.

Answer (score 1):

## **C, 51 Characters**

```
float round(float x, int n)
{
    return(long)(x*pow(10,n)+(x>0?0.5:-0.5))/pow(10,n);
}
```

Not including the function headers, it's 51 characters.